# Cancel a notification inside a Bundle created using setGroup

Tags: android, notifications

I have multiple notifications stacked in a bundle created using the:

```
setGroup("groupname");
```

and the

```
setGroupSummary(true);
```

methods.

Each notification has an action. The intent inside the action pendingIntent contains the notification id which can be used to cancel the notification.

When the notifications are NOT bundled into a group and displayed inside a summary notification, calling NotificationManager.cancel(id) cancels the notification promptly.

However, If the notifications are grouped and ARE summarized, the NotificationManager.cancel(id) does nothing.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this.

The pending intent for action is as follows:

```
  Intent notificationSettingsIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotificationSettingsActivity.class);
  notificationSettingsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  notificationSettingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
  notificationSettingsIntent.putExtra("fromNotification",true);
  notificationSettingsIntent.putExtra("notif_id",counterOfValidNotifications+6666);
  //Log.d("FragmentCreate","Setting notif_id inside action button "+(counterOfValidNotifications+6666)+" for restid "+c.getInt(restidindex));
  PendingIntent notificationSettingsActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,(int)(System.currentTimeMillis()%10000),notificationSettingsIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

  notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_notifications_off_black_24dp,"Notification Options",notificationSettingsActivityPendingIntent);
```

The notif_id inside this intent is received inside the activity specified and here i basically call cancel(id).

Comment: I m also facing the same issue. Have bundled notification. And want to cancel on of the notification from that bundle.But it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't help you as even i have not found an answer to this part...

Comment: notificationManager.notify(GROUP_ID, groupBuilder.build());
                    notificationManager.notify((int) messageId, builder.build()); this is my code. And when i complete reply action on one of the notification, i want to cancel that notification using messageId, but it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376736/not-able-to-cancel-bundled-notification-after-successfully-reply-action-in-andro

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)(System.currentTimeMillis()%10000)
```

This is not enough. If all your notifications are created within the millisecond they'll have just one `PendingIntent`. You set the flags as oneshot, so after the first one they won't be even delivered.

Comment: That's not even the problem man.... I'm fine with that, the issue is the notification not getting removed from the group

Comment: @Kushan this is exactly the issue. Try setting random values instead of this and you'll immediately see the difference.